Vue @click="show = true" error Replace `show·=·true` with `(show·=·true)` eslint(prettier/perttier)
error
@click="show = true"
fix
@click="(show = true)"
.eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:vue/strongly-recommended',
    'standard',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: ['simple-import-sort', 'import'],
  rules: {
    'simple-import-sort/imports': 'error',
    'simple-import-sort/exports': 'error',
    'import/newline-after-import': 'error',
    'vue/multi-word-component-names': 'off',
  },
}

.prettierrc.js
/** @type {import('prettier').Config} */
module.exports = {
  singleQuote: true,
  printWidth: 100,
  tabWidth: 2,
  useTabs: false,
  semi: false,
  trailingComma: 'all',
  endOfLine: 'auto',
  htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: 'ignore',
  overrides: [
    {
      files: '*.json',
      options: {
        trailingComma: 'none',
      },
    },
  ],
}

version
"eslint": "^8.57.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
"prettier": "^3.3.2",
What are the rules of prettier?

Prettier is a code formatter. It does not lint the code and it's not recommended to integrate prettier via ESLint. Instead, you should use the Prettier CLI.

Also in Prettier v3.4.0 there was a small issue with the formatter and it wanted to add parentheses to the event handlers, however this issue has been fixed with prettier v3.4.1. https://github.com/prettier/prettier/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#341

@JSONDerulo This looks like an answer here, consider posting it as it seems to be valuable. IIRC there were similar questions already

In prettier v3.4.0 there is an issue with the formatting of the event handlers. If you have the following code:
<button @click="show = true"></button>

Prettier v3.4.0 formats it to:
<button @click="(show = true)"></button>

This is a bug which was fixed with v3.4.1, see the changelog.
After updating the prettier version, prettier should accept the given code format.
